# Issue with running cassandra ccm (cassandra cluster manager)

Tags: cassandra

Issue with Installing cassandra cluster manager (ccm) and run it?

I tried both method:

Method 1:

1. clone ccm from github, do the setup and run,
2. ccm create --cassandra-version 1.2.2 --nodes 3 --start test

but node1, node2, node3 never starts. ccm status reports all node as 'DOWN'. When I try, ccm node1 ring, it complains of, Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.

Exactly same scenario when, in place of version, I install cassandra from source and in CASSANDRA_HOME directory, I do this,
- ccm create --cassandra-dir=/xxxx/cassandra --nodes 4 --start test

Any clue? whats going on? I do have openjdk-7 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that my loopback on 127.0.0.2 and 127.0.0.3 was down and had to change the status from down to UP using ifconfig command. Once done, all nodes came back up using:
ccm create --cassandra-version 1.2.2 --nodes 3 --start test

Optionally, you could start each node after creating them by using:
- ccm node1 start
- ccm node2 start
- ccm node3 start

don't forget to check - ccm node1 ring - to check if all gossip channels are up and load is shared.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide with what commands to executed to change the loopback status? I have similar problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964211/unable-to-run-cassandra-cluster-manager-in-mac-os-x-unavailablesocketerror

Comment: @eagertoLearn - look into ifup, ifdown, ifquery.