# unable to run cassandra cluster manager in Mac OS X: UnavailableSocketError

Tags: macos, cassandra

I have successfully installed `ccm` and created a test cluster

```
ccm list
 *tutorial
ccm status
node1: DOWN (Not initialized)
```

node1:DOWN is abnormal:
I still tried

```
ccm start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenvs/cqlengCass/bin/ccm", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('ccm==1.1', 'ccm')
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenvs/cqlengCass/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 487, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenvs/cqlengCass/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1344, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/Users/Documents/virtualenvs/cqlengCass/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ccm-1.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/ccm", line 72, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ccmlib/cmds/cluster_cmds.py", line 432, in run
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ccmlib/cluster.py", line 232, in start
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ccmlib/node.py", line 377, in start
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/ccmlib/common.py", line 272, in check_socket_available
ccmlib.common.UnavailableSocketError: Inet address 127.0.0.1:9042 is not available: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

I read through this [post.](https://github.com/pcmanus/ccm/issues/87) but not totally clear what needs to be node:

Comment: Is it possible that you started another instance of Cassandra -- you can check that (e.g. `ps ax | grep CassandraDaemon`)? Or that you did a `ccm start` before and haven't shutdown the "cluster" with `ccm stop`?

Comment: @AlexPopescu: I killed all cassandraDaemon thread. Started a new one, then did ccm start

Comment: You do _not_ need to start Cassandra by yourself. ccm will do that for you. So, stop all Cassandra instances. Then just do `ccm start`. When done, `ccm stop`.

Comment: @AlexPopescu I stopped cassandra thread. I then did ccm start. Now I get this error: [node1 ERROR] Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon

Comment: go through the `ccm` README step by step (don't skip). The error above makes me think that the cluster you have created is not correctly configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things to have to consider:

1. `CCM` will start `cassandra` instance automatically. so you don't have to do it by yourself. If you have started it use kill PID (PID is process ID which you can get by typing `ps aux | grep cassandra` in commandline on POSIX machines )
2. you have to set `CASSANDRA_HOME`. 
   This is how it looks it mine .bash_profile. you can put in either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. But `source` it for it to set to current environment

   `export CASSANDRA_HOME=/Users/Documents/cassandra`